# len() of unsized object in Python when using scipy's pearson correlation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two datasets of two lists of numbers and want to calculate the correlation and p-value using scipy stats in Python. The number of numbers in the two lists are equal.
The code:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

a=open("a.txt")
b=open("b.txt")
print pearsonr(a,b)`
```

But, it returns: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`

What is wrong here?

The two txt files are two list of numbers, which is like "[12,13,5,7]"

Comment: Have you tried converting the files to arrays? Because I think pearonr() only accepts array like arguments, which files are not

Comment: @wastk I'm really new to programming so not sure whether I understand what you mean...the file is like "[12,5,3,5...]". Should I convert it to other format?

Comment: are the files of equal length

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a = open("a.txt")` assigns a reader of the file to a and NOT the array the content represents.
You would have to create the array yourself. I'm not really familiar with scipy, but I guess the code would have to look something like that

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

a=open("a.txt")
b=open("b.txt")

a_array = create_array(a)
b_array = create_array(b)
print pearsonr(a_array,b_array)

def create_array(file):
    ret = []
    for line in file:
        line.replace('[','')
        line.replace(']','')
        ret = line.split(',') 
        map(lambda x: int(x), ret)

    return ret
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it works! Can I ask one more question? I used a_array=np.array(a) to convert the list to array (I imported np), but it doesn't work. So to create an array, I have to def 'create_array' everytime?

Comment: You can import the file and use the method in other files
See here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html for more infomration

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) to make list objects:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr,array
import ast

a=open("a.txt")
b=open("b.txt")

c=ast.literal_eval(a.read())
d=ast.literal_eval(b.read())
print type(c)
print type(d)
print pearsonr(array(c,dtype='int'),array(d,dtype='int'))
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
(1.0, 0.0)

a.close()
b.close()
```

For multiple lists:

```
a_r = a.readlines()
a_b = b.readlines()
a_lists = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in a_r]
b_lists = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in a_b]


for i,j in enumerate(a_lists):
    arr_a = array(j,dtype='int')
    arr_b = array(b_lists[i],dtype='int')
    print '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(arr_a,arr_b,pearsonr(arr_a,arr_b))

a.close()
b.close()
[1 2 3 4], [5 6 7 8], (1.0, 0.0)
[ 4  5 10 13], [ 4  5  6 15], (0.86845192970523943, 0.13154807029476057)
```